# Copy file to Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, file-transfer, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get a single file to play on my raspberry pi. I am attempting to tinker with High Level Assembly, and C, and have gotten them to compile properly. I'm just having trouble actually getting them onto the device itself. I have a feeling that there is a way to do it bis USB, like the Arduino, but as it's using a micro sd card I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: I approved a  radical change to your post so that it is easier to understand and be more helpful. If you feel this distorts the purpose of the post, rollback to the last edit.

Comment: Just to clarify - is this one of the original model A/B/B+ Raspberry Pis or the Raspberry Pi 2?

Comment: It was the raspberry pi 2 but I figured it out. Thanks Shekhar for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Turns out fat32 does allow some Operating Systems to run however, most linux distros run better on the EXT2, or EXT3 system better. I forgot about that and that's what was preventing it to work. I had to use the pi tool to set it up and finally got some treading with that.

Anyway, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Click on the arrow on the left side of the post

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is actually install Raspbian onto the Raspberry Pi if you have not already done so. You can then download [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) which is a windows based Terminal. It lets you connect to a remote Linux system and give commands to it. Using Putty you can actually send files from a Windows system to a Linux system (which Raspbian is).

The Terminal command is **scp** which stands for Secure Copy. `scp <file to send> <username>@<ip to destination machine>:<directory to store file in>`

Another option may be WinSCP

Comment: Ok thank you, ill check that out. I did have Raspbian installed but backed it up to try it. Also I have been having problems formatting my sd card. It says its a 32 gb card but after formatting it using Raspberrys tools it says its only 812 mb or so in size. I figured out that it has to be fat 32 for it to work right, but im just having no luck with getting a proper format for that card to where it can use the full 32 gigs of space. Even when i had the partitions set it showed 28.6 or so gigs on the card, which i assume is used for probably firmware and drivers, but stil im confused lol

Comment: @SammyWest: [Gibibytes != Gigabytes](https://www.bing.com/search?q=32+gigabytes+%3D+%3F+gibibytes). Also see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte#Consumer_confusion).